# SQL - replace a NULL value with a calculated value

Tags: sql, stock, portfolio

My Query shows Stock tickers, the price target I have set for the stock, and the open price.
If my price_target column has a NULL value, i want to replace it with a calculated value.
10% increase on the open.

[image]

So for example: row 3, ticker = ARCB. The price_target has a NULL value. The open is 43.7, so NULL should be replaced with 48.07.

I'm assuming I should use a CASE expression:
(case WHEN price_target IS NULL THEN ((open * 0.1) + OPEN) END)

However, this creates a new column:

[image]

How do I just replace the NULL values in the price_target column?

Comment: You can add `ELSE price_target` to the `CASE WHEN` statement and remove the `price_target` from `SELECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT ticker, 
    case WHEN price_target IS NULL THEN ((open * 0.1) + open) else price_target 
    END as price_target, 
    open 
FROM rating_open
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `coalesce` here

```
select ticker, 
  Coalesce(price_target, open * 1.1),
  open
from rating_open
```

Also to add 10%, just multiply by 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Take it out of the SELECT statement, put your case clause after a WHERE statement

Anything you put in the SELECT clause will display as a column

Comment: So like this: SELECT ticker, price_target, open
FROM rating_open
(case WHEN price_target IS NULL THEN ((open * 0.1) + open) END)